# R SQL Server ODBC connection Escape Character \ in Server Name

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect my R Studio session to my SQL Server database using library(odbc). 
However, the server name is something like "xxx\xxxx", and R is complaining about "an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""xxx\xxxx".

After some googling, I tried Server = ...  with two \s then it just complains about "Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks.

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQLServer",
                 Server = "xx\xxxx",
                 Database = "xx",
                 UID = "axx",
                 PWD = "axx",
                 Port = 1xxx)
```

SQL Server Enterprise Edition 64-bit Version 10.50.2500.0;
RStudio Version 1.1.423

Comment: In R it would definitely be `"xxx\\xxxx"` but if that gives the error that the name doesn't exist, then it thinks that name doesn't exist. Can you show some proof that you have the name correct?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved, after installing ODBC driver on the PC for SQL Server

```
#LIBRARY#
library(DBI)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

#CONNECTION#
con  <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "xxxx")
```

Thanks